# Syntax of regex incoherent

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to do a regex:

```
 static regex(version: string) {
    const match = /^([0-9])*\.([0-9])*\.([0-9])*-([0-9])*-(toto)$/.exec(version);
    return parseInt(match[1]) + "." + parseInt(match[2]) + "." + parseInt(match[3]) + "-" + parseInt(match[4]);
}
```

When version is:

- 1.0.0-7-toto, it return me 1.0.0-7 so it's good

But when is:

- 1.0.0-17-toto,  it return me 1.0.0-7 and not 1.0.0-17

Where is my problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Your repeats are *outside* of the capturing groups.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments your repeats should be in the capture groups.

Please try:

```
 static regex(version: string) {
    const match = /^([0-9]*)\.([0-9]*)\.([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)-(toto)$/.exec(version);
    return parseInt(match[1]) + "." + parseInt(match[2]) + "." + parseInt(match[3]) + "-" + parseInt(match[4]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of parsing the `\d+` into numbers, just to immediately convert them back to strings? You don't even change the radix. Same for the entire pattern. You take it apart, just to immediately put it the same way back together.

And if your string doesn't match the pattern your function will throw when trying to access the groups.

Here a simpler version, imo.

```js
function regex(version) {
  const match = /^\d+\.\d+\.\d+-\d+(?=-toto$)/.exec(version);
  return match && match[0];
}


console.log(regex("1.0.0-7-toto"));
console.log(regex("1.0.0-17-toto"));
console.log(regex("1.0.0-17-abba"));
```